# How do we find the closed form for $\int_{0}^{\pi/2}{\mathrm dx\over \sqrt{\sin^6x+\cos^6x}}?$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

We would like to find out the closed form for integral $(1)$

> $$\int_{0}^{\pi/2}{\mathrm dx\over \sqrt{\sin^6x+\cos^6x}}\tag1$$

**An attempt:**

We may write

$x^6+y^6=(x^2+y^2)(x^4-x^2y^2+y^4)$

Let $x=\sin x$ and $y=\cos x$

$x^6+y^6=(x^4-x^2y^2+y^4)$

Simplified down to

$x^6+y^6=\sin^4 x+\cos2x\cos^2x$

$x^6+y^6=\sin^2 x-{1\over 4}\sin^2 2x+\cos2x\cos^2x$

$(1)$ becomes

$$\int_{0}^{\pi/2}{\mathrm dx\over \sqrt{\sin^2 x-{1\over 4}\sin^2 2x+\cos2x\cos^2x}}\tag2$$

The power has reduced but looked more messier

How else can we  evaluate $(1)$?

Comment: $$\sin^6x+\cos^6x=1-3\sin^2x\cos^2x$$

$$\dfrac1{\sqrt{1-3\sin^2x\cos^2x}}=\dfrac{\sec^2x}{\sqrt{\sec^4x-3\tan^2x}}=\dfrac{\sec^2x}{\sqrt{1-\tan^2x+\tan^4x}}$$

Comment: wolfram alpha says that $$\sin^6 x+\cos^6 x=\frac38\cos(4x)+\frac58$$ The identity surely comes from rearrange the expression using the exponential definition of sine and cosine function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using  [this](https://www.quora.com/How-can-you-simplify-cos-6x-+-sin-6x-to-1-3-sin-2x-cos-2x),$$\sin^6(x)+\cos^6(x)=1-\frac 34 \sin^2(2x)$$  makes $$\int{ dx\over \sqrt{\sin^6(x)+\cos^6(x)}}=\int{ dx\over \sqrt{1-\frac 34\sin^2(2x)}}=\frac{1}{2} F\left(2 x\left|\frac{3}{4}\right.\right)$$  where appears the elliptic integral of the first kind.

Using the bounds, the result simplifies to $$K\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)\approx 2.15652$$  which is the complete elliptic integral of the first kind.

If I may suggest, have a look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_integral).

Comment: can $K(3/4)$ can it be represent in terms of $\Gamma$ and $\pi$, I am sure I have see this number 2.156...  has a closed form on one of wolfram page.

Comment: @Bui. Inverse symbolic calculators do not find anything.

Answer (score 2):

Using the substitution $x=\arctan t$ the given integral boils down to:
$$ I=\int_{0}^{+\infty}\sqrt{\frac{1+t^2}{1+t^6}}\,dt=\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{dt}{\sqrt{t^4-t^2+1}}=\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{dt}{\sqrt{(t^2+\omega^2)(t^2+\bar{\omega}^2)}} $$
(with $\omega=\exp\left(\frac{\pi i}{3}\right)$ ) that is a complete elliptic integral of the first kind. Such integral can be computed through the [AGM mean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic%E2%80%93geometric_mean) $\text{AGM}(a,b)=\text{AGM}\left(\frac{a+b}{2},\sqrt{ab}\right)$:
$$ I = \frac{\pi}{2\,\text{AGM}(\omega,\bar{\omega})} = \color{red}{\frac{\pi}{\text{AGM}(1,2)}}.$$
In particular, the integral is bounded between $\pi(12-8\sqrt{2})$ and $\pi\sqrt[4]{\frac{2}{9}}$.